# Using a command defined with \newcommand prevents subsequent characters from being printed

Tags: macros

I have the following command defined in a LaTeX document:

```
\newcommand{\citeme}[1]{\hl{[citation]}}
```

where `\hl` is a command that highlights the text in its arguments from the [`soul`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul) package. The purpose of using the command I defined above is to render a text that reminds me that I need to add a citation to the text.

E.g.

```
Hello world \citeme Hello again \citeme
```

results in the following:

[image]

The problem is that, as you can see, the letter `H` from the second `Hello` is missing. Why does that happen? How can I make sure I get the characters following my command printed?

Comment: You are telling TeX that `\citeme` takes an argument by using `[1]` in the `\newcommand`. Just leave it out completely obtaining: `\newcommand{\citeme}{\hl{[citation]}}`.

Comment: You are right @whlt3, I feel dumb. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, even without the argument, `\citeme` will remove spaces after it.  You will have to write `\citeme\ ` or use the `xspace` package in these cases.

Comment: From experience, I would suggest not using a device like this. Too often, when I thought I could rely on my memory batting out the text and find supporting references later, I had to change the text when I actually got around to adding the citations, because my remembered knowledge was incomplete or no longer up to date. So, now I research and select references immediately before I write anything.

Comment: You could also simply add `\cite{}` without any content. This should add an empty `[]` in the document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you have defined the `\citeme` command right now it takes an argument. So it scans for an argument and finds the `H` from `Hello`. If you were to change the definition to `\newcommand{\citeme}{\hl{[citation]}}` it will work as expected.